# For what values $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ does $x^3-17x^2+mx-n^2$ have all roots in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is from Tengan's number theory book. He  asked to detemine all positive $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x^3-17x^2+mx-n^2=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. This will hold if and only if:

$$\begin{cases}
abc=n^2\\
ab+bc+ac=m\\
a+b+c=17
\end{cases}$$

There will exist (possibly negative) integers $n$ and $m$ satisfying this if and only if $abc=n^2$ and $a+b+c=17$.

Equivalently, there will exist $n$ and $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $ab(17-a-b)$ is a perfect square.

**EDIT 1:** There are many non-solutions (because either $n\leq 0$ or $m\leq 0$), though this method will take us nowhere!

**1st Family:** We could write $17=a+b$ and there are infinetly many $(a,b)=(z,17-z)$. Thus, we have for all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$, a polynomial with integer roots if:

$$\begin{cases}
n=0\\
m=z(17-z)
\end{cases}
$$

However $n=0$, so this is of no interest to us.

**2nd Family:** I tried setting $a=17k$ and $b=17(18-k)$ because this enables us to extract a $17^4$ power, namely:

$$ab(17-a-b)=-17^4k(18-k)$$

By setting $k=-9l$ we have:

$$ab(17-a-b)=-17^4(-9l)(18-9l)=17^4\cdot 9^2 l(2+l)$$

For $l=0,2$ we have one extra non solution:

$$ l=0 \: \text{or}\:  2\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
m=-88434\\
n^2=0
\end{cases}$$

**EDIT 2:**
There are basically two cases to consider if $abc=n^2>0$:

**Case I:**  $a,b,c>0$:

We may assume without loss of generality $a\leq b\leq c$ because the equations are symetric.
If $a+b+c=17$, we have that all prime elements in $n$ must come from $\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$. If $p\geq 7$ appears in $n$. Then we must have $49$ appearing in $a,b,c$ which is absurd, or $7$ appearing in two elements which is also absurd because it would require $ a+b+c\geq 4+7+7$.

Therefore all primes appearing in $n$ must satisfy $p\leq 5$. However, if $p=5$ appears, then we have that these factor must be split into two elements in $a,b,c$, (because $25$ is two large) hence

$$(a,b,c)\in\{(5,5,7),(2,5,10)\}$$

The only solution in this case is $(a,b,c)=(2,5,10)$ which yields $n^2=100$ and $m=10+50+20=80$.

If $p= 3$ I think we only have $(a,b,c)=(4,4,9)$ and hence $144=n^2$ and $m=16+36+36=88$.

Finally if we only have $p=2$, I think this is the only one to work: $(a,b,c)=(1,8,8)$ and hence $n^2=64$ and $m=8+8+64=80$

**Case II:** $a,b<0$ and $c>0$

$c=17-a-b$ implies that $m=ab+bc+ca=ab+(a+b)(17-a-b)=ab-(a+b)^2+17(a+b)=-a^2-ab-b^2+17(a+b)<0$, which yields no solution.

---

So I think $(n^2,m)\in \{(64,80),(144,88),(100,80)\}$ are the only solutions but I could easily have forgotten to consider things in the first case and this solution is extremely ugly (if it is even correct).

Comment: In that case, take $m=80,n=10$. Then the roots are $2,5,10$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. There seems to be many solutions. Do you think there is a systematic approach to find them? I have tried working on $a,b,c>0$ and it is a total mess.

Comment: Do you have additional conditions like n is a prime or something else?

Comment: Nope, no additional requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you've missed just one solution, $(m, n) = (90, 12)$.

Like you write, it's enough to find $a, b$ such that $a b (17 - a - b)$ is a perfect square.

We can reduce the search space as follows: Since $m, n > 0$, the signs of the coefficients of the polynomial alternate, and so Descartes' Rule of Signs gives that its roots, $a, b, c$, are all positive, i.e., reducing to your Case I. By relabeling, we may assume that $a \leq b \leq c$, so that $17 = a + b + c \geq 3 a$, hence $a \leq 5$. At this point it's not too much work just to check each case $a \in \{1, \ldots, 5\}$ separately. For each case we need only consider the $b$ satisfying $a \leq b \leq \frac12 (17 - a)$.

We can use modular arithmetic to further prune cases. For example:

- **Case $a = 1$.** The equation reduces to $b (16 - b) = n^2$, with $1 \leq b \leq 8$. Reducing modulo $4$ gives $-b^2 = n^2 \pmod 4$, so $b \equiv n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Thus $b \in \{4, 8\}$, and only $8$ gives a solution: $(a, b, c) = (1, 8, 8)$, $\boxed{(m, n) = (80, 8)}$.
- **Case $a = 3$.** The equation reduces to $3 b (14 - b) = n^2$, and $3 \leq b \leq 7$. Reducing modulo $3$ gives $b \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and reducing modulo $4$ gives $b \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, so $b = 6$, which yields the solution $(a, b, c) = (3, 6, 8)$, $\boxed{(m, n) = (90, 12)}$.

I'll leave the cases $a = 2, 4, 5$ to you.

Comment: So organized! I love everything about your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement that $m$ and $n$ be positive greatly restricts the possible values of $a$ and $b$. For $n$ to be positive you must have $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$ and $a+b\neq17$. For $m$ note that
$$m=ab+ac+bc=ab+a(17-a-b)+b(17-a-b)=17(a+b)-(a^2+ab+b^2).$$
Of course $a^2+ab+b^2>0$ and so we must have
$$17(a+b)>a^2+ab+b^2>0$$
In particular $a+b>0$. Without loss of generality $a\geq b$, and so $a>0$ and $|b|\leq a$, and
$$17>\frac{a^2+ab+b^2}{a+b}=a+\frac{b^2}{a+b}.$$
This shows that $a<17$, and so we have $0<a<17$ and $0<|b|\leq a$. From here you can do a routine check.

Comment: It seems to me that you can draw the conclusion more quickly: Since the signs of the coefficients of the polynomial strictly alternate, its roots, $a, b, c$, must all be positive. But then $a < a + b + c = 17$.

Comment: @TravisWillse I'm not so familiar with that result (is it Descartes' rule of signs?). Does it not tell you that there are at most $3$ positive roots, and the number of positive roots is odd?

Comment: I guess you get exactly $3$ positive roots because by the same rule there are at most $0$ negative roots. Feel free to write up your own answer.

Comment: Yes, Descartes' Rule of Signs. (+1, by the way).

Comment: I guess this is mostly what I did after EDIT II, but I am not that sure how to systematically count things. I found three solutions. +1, by the way.